# Custom Variables with Google Analytics for low end Mobile devices (no javascript)

Tags: php, mobile, google-analytics, analytics, mxit

I'm working on the Mxit platform & would like to create and capture some custom variables to store in Google Analytics.

With Mxit portals, it's not the usual communication between browser & web server. It's phone app, mxit server, web server. Mxit sits in the middle, which means we can’t directly capture user specific info.

Mxit does however set custom headers with additional user info, which can be captured for Analytics via custom variables.

We can't make use of javascript, so I’ve installed the Analytics for mobile php script, which creates and appends data to the gif image.

I've set the custom variables on a normal website via javascript and using GA debug I copied the utme parameter and added it to the GA for mobile php code to append to manually append to the gif query string.

Here's a quick, over simplified example:

The custom values I'd like to set.

```
$id = $headers['mxitID'];
$country = $headers['country'];
$gender = $headers['gender'];
$age = $headers['age'];
```

and here I'm appending to the gif query string

```
&utme=8(MxitID*Country*Gender*Age)9($id*$country*$gender*$age)11(1*1*1*1)
```

The way I understand it, 8() represents the custom variable names, 9() represents the custom variable values and 11() represents the scope.

It's been 2 days now, and there is still no custom variable information in Google Analytics.

I'm checking Visitors > Custom Variables

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As far as I know the Google Analytics implementation for low end devices is very limited. I remember trying to implement Custom Variables with the PHP library and I think this is not supported. Your implementation looks correct, have your tried printing the full path of the GIF request to troubleshoot ? Not sure if that is available in your framework, but the Mobile SDKs have better option - for instance you could use the Android SDK to implement Custom Variables : http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/android/#usingCustomVariables

Comment: To anyone still trying to implement custom variables using a server side approach. There is a project that supports this here: http://code.google.com/p/php-ga/ The project uses PHP 5.3

Comment: You can use the following code to implement Google Analytics within Mxit Applications developed in PHP: https://github.com/n1c/mxit-php-ga I've beeen using it for a few months and it seems pretty reliable. There have been a few times where I scratched my head trying to figure out why Google Analytics wasn't working only to discover that the curl executable wasn't installed on my system, so keep an eye out for that, or alternatively change it to use the PHP CURL library instead.

Answer (score 1):

Google has a server-side solution just for this issue. You can find the code here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/other/mobileWebsites

Here's an implementation of that library

```
<?php
    class GoogleAnalytics {
        const ACCOUNT = "ACCOUNT ID GOES HERE";
        const PIXEL = "/ga.php";

        public static function getImageUrl() {
            $url .= self::PIXEL . '?';
            $url .= 'utmac=' . self::ACCOUNT;
            $url .= '&utmn=' . rand(0, 0x7fffffff);

            $referer = !empty($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]) ? $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] : '-';
            $url .= '&utmr=' . urlencode($referer);

            if (!empty($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])) {
                $url .= "&utmp=" . urlencode($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
            }

            $url .= '&guid=ON';

            return str_replace('&', '&amp;', $url);
        }
    }
?>
```

And then in your view you do:

```
<img src="<?php echo GoogleAnalytics::getImageUrl() ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some code for this.

You can modify it as you wish. :{D

https://github.com/WillemLabu/ga-collection